# When I read this file in pyspark, there are strange symbols that are originally accents, instead I would like to get the letter

Tags: python, pyspark, encoding

When I read my file in pyspark or whatever (in pandas for example), there are strange symbols that are originally accents. I would like to retrieve whether my letter with accent, whether my letter without accent, but not this strange symbol (see the image below).

my code is :

```
df = spark.sql(func_sql(date))

df = df.distinct()
```

[image]

In this name column, there are black rhombus with a white question mark inside, I don't want that please (even if I save it in excel file with to_excel and then read this file with pd.read_excel, there are these strange symbols). How to proceed please ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: You have an encoding issue. Try specifying unicode / utf-8 when accessing the data. Then you will have to translate chracater with accent to another one without accent.